# REGEX Visual Studio 2013 find and change

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I want to change naming of my class names and methods in tests. There are hundreds of them, they are very long and hard to read. Underscores will help.

I created REGEX:

```
(public class [A-Z][a-z]*(_[A-Z][a-z]*)*)(?<x>[A-Z])
```

Replace pattern: `$1_${x}`

that gives my example:
From: `public class VeryLongClassNameTestScenarioTwentySeven`

To: `public class Very_LongClassNameTestScenarioTwentySeven`

Next use: `public class Very_Long_ClassNameTestScenarioTwentySeven`

Next use: `public class Very_Long_Class_NameTestScenarioTwentySeven`

After using many times all names should be changed. Can you help me find regular expression that will do it at once?

I suppose regular expressions in VS do not support converting letter from upper, to lower case?

Thanks

Comment: you could use an external tool to perform the change.

Comment: Like Grepwin :) http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html

Comment: It solves upper case problem.
But still need regular expression. Any idea how to create one that will do it all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to my VS workstation right now, but I think the following *should* work:

Find: `(?<=public class .*?)([a-z])([A-Z])`

Replace with: `$1_$2`

(I tested on http://regexstorm.net/tester )

---

***Edit:*** Now that I'm sitting in front of my VS workstation, here's the result of my testing:

It "kinds of" work... strangely, with the following code:

```
public class ThisIsLongClassName
{ }

public class AnotherLongClassName
{ }

public class WhoaThisNameIsEvenLonger
{ }
```

Now, testing with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>:

- If I do "Find Next", it **properly** jumps between the locations where substitutions *should* take place. So the regex is correct.
- However, when I clicked "Replace", **it replaces the line below the line being highlighted**. E.g., the highlight is on `sI` of the first line, the change happens on `rL` of the *second* line
- Lastly, clicking "Replace All" doesn't do anything

I think VS2013 is b0rked. At least mine is.

---

***Edit 2:*** So, I recommend you create a small program and let it 'have a go' through your files. Will be much simpler regex, since all you have to do is ensure that the `.TrimStart()`-ed line starts with `'public class'`, then do a simple regex replace of `([a-z])([A-Z])` with `$1_$2` on that line.

Comment: Thanks for help. One thing- I also thought my VS is broken. But for regex [a-z] and [A-Z] to work you must check 'Match case'. Maybe you have forgotten.

Comment: Nope, didn't forget that one. As I've written, simple "Find" works properly. Replace using regex is simply broken.

Comment: Probably a bug in Visual Studio, I've noticed similar behavior when perform replacements with more complex regular expressions. It will often fail to do anything with `Replace All` and using just `Replace` will have it perform the operation on alternating instances. Multiple runs, pressing [Alt]+[R] will eventually get all but the one of the instances. Not as good as having it work correctly with `Replace All` but much better than doing it all by hand!